# how to install \lib\runpy.py

Tags: python, pyqt5, fbs

Maybe it is a beginner question, sorry ...

On Windows 10 I tried to build an executable file using Qt5 and fbs (python 3.7, 64bit).

I installed Qt5 and fbs using pip.

1. fbs startproject - worked
2. fbs run - worked
3. fbs freeze - following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\am\python37-64\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\am\python37-64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\AM\Python37-64\Scripts\fbs.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "c:\am\python37-64\lib\site-packages\fbs\__main__.py", line 17, in _main fbs.cmdline.main()
File "c:\am\python37-64\lib\site-packages\fbs\cmdline.py", line 32, in main fn(*args)
File "c:\am\python37-64\lib\site-packages\fbs\builtin_commands\__init__.py", line 120, in freeze freeze_windows(debug=debug)
File "c:\am\python37-64\lib\site-packages\fbs\freeze\windows.py", line 18, in freeze_windows run_pyinstaller(args, debug)
File "c:\am\python37-64\lib\site-packages\fbs\freeze\__init__.py", line 47, in run_pyinstaller run(args, check=True)
File "c:\am\python37-64\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "c:\am\python37-64\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__ restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "c:\am\python37-64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

There really is no file `lib\runpy.py`, but how to get it?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by _There really is no file..._? Is there really no file `c:\am\python37-64\lib\runpy.py`?

Comment: exactly that, there is no such file

Comment: But you find that file in your call stack: `"c:\aa\python37-64\lib\runpy.py", line 193`. What is the actual folder you work in `aa\`, `am\`, or `AM\`?

Comment: Sorry, misspelling in line one, I reedited it. The correct spelling of the path is C:\AM\Python37-64, but I think this doesn't matter on windows. The runpy.py doesn't exist and that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Are there any hints?